# JavaScript delay in for loop (with p5.js)

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, settimeout, delay

How can I get a delay per every draw point in this programm? 
Btw. i am using p5.js

```
function points_oben() {
    for (let a = 0; a < koords.length; a++) {
    setTimeout(function() {    
    for (var i = 0; i < koords.length; i++) {  
    strokeWeight(10);   
    stroke('blue');   
    point(koords[i].xkoord, koords[i].ykoord);   } 
      }, 3000); 
     }   
    }
```

When the function run it delays 3s and then all points and not only point by point are drawn.

Comment: There's no `setTimeout` in your script. Please add a [mcve] of the code that _"doesn't work"_ and explain what _"doesn't work"_ means exactly.

Comment: Sorry my fault. I taught this might work like this:

`function points_oben() {

  for (let a = 0; a < koords.length; a++) {

  setTimeout(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < koords.length; i++) {

  strokeWeight(10);
  stroke('blue');
  point(koords[i].xkoord, koords[i].ykoord);
  }
  }, 3000); 
}  
}`

But when the function run it delays 3s and then all points and not only point by point are drawn.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62467362/edit) your question instead of adding it as a comment (for future questions)

Comment: Done, its my first questions sorry for this.